# In R how can you replace elements in a long list while preserving the original list structure?

Tags: r

I need to replace each value in a list while preserving the original structure.  I have a vector.  I need to find the minimum value in the vector that is greater than or equal to each value in the list.  Then replace the value in the list with this minimum value.  The list is long enough that a loop will not work.  Is there any way to do this with an apply or related function?

```
a <- list(x = 1, y = c(2,3), z = 5)
b <- c(1,2,4,6,7)

> a
$x
[1] 1

$y
[1] 2 3

$z
[1] 5
```

What I would like to produce is a modified version of a such that

```
> a
$x
[1] 1

$y
[1] 2 4

$z
[1] 6
```

Using lapply I can get close,

```
> lapply(unlist(a), function(x) min(b[b>=x]))
$x
[1] 1

$y1
[1] 2

$y2
[1] 4

$z
[1] 6
```

but the structure is no longer preserved as there is now a `$y1` and `$y2` instead of just a `$y` with two elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`relist()` wraps a vector 'flesh' around the shape of list 'skeleton'. So use `unlist(unname(a))` to get a vector of values (without names, which as you see in your example are non-sensical and expensive to construct). Apply your criterion to each element (using `vapply()`, which is a little bit more rigorous than your lapply), and then use `relist()` to recover the original shape

```
v = unlist(unname(a))
result = vapply(v, function(x, b) min(b[b>=x]), numeric(1), b)
relist(result, a)
```

The `vapply()` is still loop. A faster version is to use `findInterval()`, something like

```
i = findInterval(v, b)
result = ifelse(b[i] == v, b[i], b[i + 1])
```

which requires that `b` is sorted (and probably I haven't got the end points correct).

Comment: Brilliant!  Thank you.  I have spent days searching for a way to do this.